# how to call functions in external typescript file from HTML

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to reach a function that I created in a seperate typescript file but I feel like I'm missing something because it's not working, maybe some routing?

My inputfield: (inside groepdef-edit-component.html)

```
<input type="number" (blur)="Utils.SetTariefIfEmpty($event)"
```

I imported the `export class Utils`

My typescript file: (inside groepdef.edit.component.ts)

```
import { Utils } from '../Utils/Utils';
```

My Seperate TS file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'app-utils',
templateUrl: './groeperingdefinitie-contract-edit.component.html',
})

export class Utils {

  public static SetTariefIfEmpty(event: any): void {
  if (event === undefined || event === null) {
    return;
  }

  if (event.target !== undefined && event.target !== null) {
    if (event.target.value.length == 0) {
      event.target.value = 0;
    }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: You should make the Utils class a Service instead of a Component

Comment: alright I'll give that a shot

Comment: @RickyMo I'm trying to set the value of the inputfield using the function, should it return the value or is it capable of changing the field's value instantly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the function, you will need to create a service and inject that service into your component to use.

service (util.service.ts)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})

export class UtilService {

  public setTariefIfEmpty(event: any): void {
     if (event === undefined || event === null) {
       return;
     }
  }

}
```

Now you need to inject and import this into your component (groepdef.edit.component.ts):

```
import { UtilService } from '..PATH';
......
constructor(public utilService:UtilService) {}
```

In your HTML (groepdef-edit-component.html):

```
<input type="number" (blur)="utilService.setTariefIfEmpty($event)"/>
```

Comment: looks promising, I was set on this path thanks to @RickyMo but your visual presentation's very helpful.

Comment: curious question, can I edit the field inside the service? right now I'm sending an event which contains a target etc, can i edit the value of the target and does that change get returned to the actual field?  **EDIT** : nevermind, Yes it works

Answer (score 1):

- In your case `Utils` should not be defined as an Angular Component
- You can create `Utils.ts` file and export functions from it directly. This can be handy when your functions don't rely on any other Angular features(eg. any Angular service)

```ts
    export someFunction(someArg: any): any {
       ...
    }
```

- You can create an Angular service `UtilityService` when your function has some other dependencies or in case when you want to perform component communication or maybe HTTP calls

```ts
    @Injectable({
        providedIn: 'root',
      })
      export class UtilService { ... }
```

In your case **2nd point** i.e exporting functions should work. If you follow that approach, then you can utilize the function in your component `ts` file as:

```ts
    import { someFunction } from '<path_to_Utils.ts>';
     @Component({...})
     export class YourComponent {
       onBlur(event: Event) {
          someFunction(event);
       }
     }
```

HTML file:

```html
   <input type="number" (blur)="onBlur($event)" />
```

Comment: thank you for your contribution, unfortunately I already accepted an answer though.
still +1 cause it should work

Answer (score 0):

The reason that your template file is not accessing your `SetTariefIfEmpty()` is that you haven't declared your separate .ts file in your module file.

So, declare your Utils class in `_modules.ts_` file.